# Make border fit around text

Tags: html, css

I need to wrap the border around the text so it fits and center the text at the same time. I found a temporary solution in using `display: inline;` makes the border fit the text but when I try to use `text-align: center;` it does not align it. So I found using `display: block;` fixed it but I can't use display block and inline at the same time so I am stuck.

```
<p1 class="frequently">Frequently Ask Question</p1>

.frequently{
    color: rgb(232 87 61);
    border: solid rgb(251 244 239);
    border-radius: 2rem;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: wait. There is no such thing called `<p1>` tag in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `width: fit-content` to your css, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `display: block` with `text-align: center`. Or you can use `display: flex; justify-content: center`

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the text in a container. Apply `display: inline-block;` to that container and center the container using `text-align: center;` on its parent.

```css
.frequently-container {
 text-align: center; /* This centers the inline-block container */
}

.frequently {
 color: rgb(232, 87, 61);
 border: solid rgb(251, 244, 239);
 border-radius: 2rem;
 display: inline-block; /* Allows the border to fit the text and be centered */
 padding: 10px; /* Optional: Adds some space around the text inside the border */
}
```

```html
<div class="frequently-container">
 <p class="frequently">Frequently Ask Question</p>
</div>
```